# What's is the relationship/difference between NSCell and NSControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I come from iOS background and when creating custom controls, you simply subclass `UIControl`. I am trying to build a custom `NSSlider` (one with 2 knobs instead of one) and noticed that there are 2 classes to deal with `NSControl` and `NSCell`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for performance reasons in the past. It made it possible to reuse cells without always creating new ones for example in a table. Additionally you did not have very deep view hierarchies, being a problem 10 years ago.

Please note that `NSCell` works completely different from what you know in iOS, esp. it is no view.